# Asp Net Core 2.0 authentication based on request

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

We have configured ASP Net with Windows Authentication, using the HttpSys implementation (no IIS), as recommended https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

```
services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

.UseHttpSys(options =>
                                {
                                    options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                                    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
                                })
```

What we would like to achieve is to ignore the NTLM challenge 401 for all requests with a specific query parameter (?Anonymous) - a switch that client can control, and just pass an anonymous user, effectively turning off the windows authentication.
I've tried following advice on https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1469, rolling out own implementation of IAuthenticationHandlerProvider, IAuthenticationHandler, but that does not stop the NTLM challenge

I've also tried setting the HttpSys to allow anonymous

```
options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
```

but that just turns off the NTLM challenge globally

Any ideas?

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: That page shows you how to allow anonymous access to certain endpoints, if that helps. You could maybe have some routing rules to allow certain URLs to be accessed anonymously (maybe instead of setting a flag) which provide whatever functionality you're going to allow anonymous users to make use of.

Comment: But...I can't see a use case for allowing anonymous access to the same endpoint which you also want to secure with windows auth? It doesn't make much sense if the user can simply bypass the auth by setting a querystring parameter? Big security hole, surely? Or have you got some code inside the specific action methods which then spot anonymous users and only give them access to certain restricted functionality, or restricted data? If so, then I think you can achieve the same goal by using separate endpoints.

Comment: Yes the implementation would detect anonymous and provide filtered data. This is for load testing, and new endpoints are not great, because we want to test the existing endpoints.

Comment: If the new endpoints provide (restricted) access to the same data, then what's the difference? If you want to test load on the data store, how about you split the load appropriately across the two URLs (based on the % of anonymous requests you anticipate), and then combine the results of load testing from both endpoints to get your total load. I'd have thought that would basically get you the same info about the capacity of the system.

Comment: Another question though - who/what are the anonymous users? Have you got non-Windows devices on the network? Are you exposing the endpoint directly to the internet so non-network users can access it (if so, don't, provide a separate one which proxies and rate-limits, etc!) ? In a standard corporate Active Directory LAN, anyone who connects should have _some_ kind of identity. Once you know their identity, you can control their access to specific data according to whether they're in the right groups, or whatever other criteria you want to apply.

Comment: Also why are you seemingly preferring the ancient NTLM protocol over Kerberos?

Comment: It's the standard TFS load testing toolkit that does not support Windows Authentication, and hence cannot call the endpoints protected with Windows Auth. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test?view=vsts It's all on internal network, but fighting the agents seems more effort than enabling anonymous. Typical users will all have clients capable of Win Auth

Comment: NTLM is recommended https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x, and hence probably less involved, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see where it recommends either one. Perhaps I just misunderstood the line where you set the schemes, since NTLM was listed first, but maybe it's just simply an either-or specification with no hierarchy.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that VSTS load tests don't support any kind of Windows Auth (Kerberos or NTLM, they _are_ quite different schemes, although they are both under the Windows Auth umbrella), or is it simply that you haven't been able to make it work yet?

Comment: I did not find any ability to even configure auth, and hence I assume it's just not a supported feature yet. Also even if it was supported, it would require defining and passing credentials, messy, just seems like opening up a can of worms. Given asp net core is all pluggable, I assumed telling it to do A or B authentication based on Query string is not rocket science

Comment: I think the problem with that idea is likely to be that, just like when you use IIS, the point at which the auth challenge happens comes way before the point where it's possible to read the querystring contents.

Comment: It's just occurred to me, you said "the implementation would detect anonymous and provide filtered data."...but also "t's the standard TFS load testing toolkit that does not support Windows Authentication....typical users will all have clients capable of Win Auth". So if, in real life, all your clients will be able to authenticate, why do you need to consider restricting the data for anonymous users? There won't be any. To get your load testing to work, surely you can just switch off Windows Auth for the duration.

Comment: I've trying to get it to work with options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;, which then requires additional code to trigger the challenge: 'In ASP.NET Core 2.x, the [Authorize] attribute requires additional configuration in Startup.cs to challenge anonymous requests for Windows authentication. The recommended configuration varies slightly based on the web server being used.' Any idea where to find it?

Comment: got it, when AllowAnonymous is true, all requests are unauthenticated by default, and then we can call HttpContext.ChallengeAsync() to invoke the challenge and hence achieve selective authentication